# Installing insight blockchain explorer - is bitcore mandatory?

Tags: bitcore, blockchain-explorer, insight-api

What I have: bitcoind on Linux running.
What I want: to have insight api+ui local website running.

Earlier it was possible to add insight querying your bitcoind. Now it seems they made some bitcore base for insight.

If I install bitcore is it gonna replace bitcoind? How do they interact?

What's the best way to have local insight explorer running now?

Answer (score 1):

Bitcore is a javascript library for interacting with Bitcoin. Bitcore is [built on top of bitcoind](https://bitcore.io/) and doesn't replace it.

[Insight](https://bitcore.io/api/explorers/) is probably the simplest way to run explorer-style queries if you've already got bitcoind set up.

Alternatively: I believe [btcd](https://github.com/btcsuite/btcd) and [Toshi](https://github.com/coinbase/toshi) offer similar functionality, but with different implementations than bitcoind.